# How a function can be applied on top of another function like ***a(b)(x,y)*** where **a** and **b** are functions and **x** and **y** are arguments?

Tags: python, function, user-defined-functions

How a function can be applied on top of another function like ***a(b)(x,y)*** where **a** and **b** are functions and **x** and **y** are arguments? Can somebody provide me with the term we call this concept along with some examples.

Comment: a(b)(x,y) doesn't make sense unless a(b) returns a function. Maybe you mean a(b(x,y))?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear how you intend for this to work. Could you give an example of how `a` and `b` would be defined, choose an input `x` and `y`, and show exactly what you intend should happen?

Answer (score 1):

For `a(b)(x, y)` to make sense, `a` needs to be a function that takes `b` as an argument and produces a new function that takes two arguments.  Here's an example:

```
>>> def a(func):
...     def wrapped(x, y):
...         return 2 * func(x, y)
...     return wrapped
...
>>> def b(x, y):
...     return x + y
...
>>> a(b)(1, 2)
6
```

In the above example `a` is a function that wraps a two-argument function and doubles its result.  `b(1, 2)` is `3`, and `a(b)(1, 2)` is therefore 6.

Answer (score 0):

a function can be applied to another function like this

```
 a(b)(x,y)
```

if the returned value from a(b) is a function that takes 2 arguments
in that case the function that is returned from a(b) will be applied on the parameters x,y

for example :

```
def mul(x,y):
    return x*y

def add5_to_func(func):
    return lambda x,y : func(x,y) + 5

print(add5_to_func(mul)(3,3)) # will print 14
```